# Can I use quickpred in Mice to impute a subset of variables from a larger set of variables in a nested longitudinal (and long) dataframe?

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice

I've tried to create a test `data.frame` to demonstrate my question but my r capacity isn't quite strong enough to even do that. I am not in a position to share my true database. I hope my question can stand on its own.

I am working with a nested longitudinal dataset that is saved as a long file (1000 subjects nested in 8 sites, 4 potential time points/subject, 68 potential predictor variables). I want to impute missing values on 4 static predictors (e.g., maternal education, family income) prior to conducting lme on the longitudinal outcomes in order to have a consistent number of cases for all models.

I am working with the package mice in r. From all that I have read, it is recommended that I use all the variables in my models and any other variables that may predict the missing values in my imputation. Given the number of variables in my models, I need something like quickpred to simplify this. But I'm getting an error that I do not understand.

I tried the following initial code for my database N2NPL, indicating `c(14, 16, 18, 19)` as the variables that I want to predict.

```
iniN2NPL <- mice(N2NPL[,c(14,16,18,19)], pred= quickpred(N2NPL,
                 minpuc = 0.25, exclude = c('ID','TypeConvNon','TypeCtPr','TypeName','CHR_converter')),
                 maxit = 0)
```

> "Error in check.predictorMatrix(setup) : 
>     The predictorMatrix has 73 rows and 73 columns. Both should be 4'

I know that `mice::quickpred` needs to be a square matrix, but is there anyway of not imputing all of the variables? Is it sufficient to include site as a predictor given the nesting of subjects within sites?

Thank you for any help directing me to the proper code or instructions on this. The examples I see all seem much simpler than mine, and thus little help with the issues I'm having.

Comment: The error you receive is trying to tell you something. You supply 4 variables to impute; but 73 variables to `quickpred`. use `quickpred(N2NPL[,c(14,16,18,19)], minpuc = 0.25)`... I'm not sure if this is your whole question or not, hence moving from an answer to a comment.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I guess I forgot a "not" (edited in now). Sorry about that. I gave up on R and went back to SPSS and realized that, at least within SPSS, I need a much simpler input (reduced categorical variable levels and categorical variables, removal of interaction effects, reduced number of predictors and imputed variables. Would still appreciate knowing more of the capacity and shortcuts with R.